# Class field modifiable inside a const method if field passed by reference?

Tags: c++, methods, reference, this

C++ student here:

Today, while writing a class, I noticed that I am able to modify a non-mutable field with a const method, if the field is passed by reference:

```
class Foo {

public:
    void func1(int & _n) const { _n = 42; }
    void func2() { func1(n); }

private:
    int n;
};

int main() {
    Foo foo;
    foo.func2();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I know that it's possible because a const method simply uses a ***this to const***, but if I pass the field as a reference, I can have direct access to it without passing through the ***this*** (I'm still learning and also still not very good at English, I may have said something wrong);

So, my question is:

What's the true utility of a const method, if a non-mutable field can be modified with a simple "trick"?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't post screenshots of code. Post code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What the true utility of a const method

It allows you to have the compiler maintain class invariants. But the compiler isn't going to protect your from shooting yourself in the foot. Inside a const member function, the compiler will only prevent modification of class members by name.

If you pass a reference to the data from outside, then it's on you. There will not be any convoluted code emitted that verifies you didn't pass a reference to a member.

The same goes for access modifiers. They only prevent access to the **name of the member**. You can break that encapsulation in many a way, the compiler isn't going to bother stopping you.

The language has mechanisms that protect you from Murphy, not Machiavelli. They won't help if you use "tricks" and work against the grain of the language. Proper encapsulation is up to the programmer, not the compiler.

Comment: The answer I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the real world you wouldn't give out public access to an internal class member. When you do this, all bets are off.

Const methods help you enforce encapsulation of a class, but you need to have this encapsulation in the first place - by marking the private data private.

Comment: Oh sorry, I know that, but the problem still holds with private fields, just call the method inside another one.

Comment: The compiler won't allow you to call a non-const method from a const one - try it.

Comment: Ok, but I still don't get it: I can still call func() from a non-const method, so that I can pass directly to it the private n field...?

Comment: You can, but you wouldn't because func already has (const) access to n. Please understand that const methods are protection from a casual mistake, but nothing will stop you to purposefully subvert the protection.

Answer (score 0):

Just define `const Foo foo;` instead of `Foo foo;` and compiler will catch the error and will be your friend again.

Answer (score 0):

> that I am able to modify a non-mutable field

You are *not* able to modify a non-mutable field, because the field isn't non-mutable. Try to declare `n` as `const` and you will see that the code will no longer compile, and that no trick (short of abusing `const_cast` and invoking undefined behaviour) will make it compile anymore.

The only `const` in your code is the one for `func1`, which turns the "invisible" `Foo* const this` (non-modifiable pointer to modifiable `Foo`) in the function into `Foo const* const this` (non-modifiable pointer to non-modifiable `Foo`).

As it turns out, those two imaginary `const`s work perfectly as designed, because both of the following attempts will fail:

- `this = nullptr; // won't compile`
- `this->n = 42;  // won't compile`

However, none of those two `const`s are related to the `_n` argument. `_n` and `this->n` refer to the same `int` object, but only the latter of the two sees it as `const`.

This leads to an important discovery. Having a `const` reference or pointer to something and having a reference or pointer to an immutable type are two different things. `int` is mutable, so whenever you have a non-`const` reference or pointer to one, modifications are possible, regardless of whether other parts of the program view the `int` object as `const`.

> What's the true utility of a const method, if a non-mutable field can
>   be modified with a simple "trick"?

As I said above, the field itself is not non-mutable. And if you need a "trick" to shut up the compiler, then you are just pushing your luck anyway.